# changing __class__.__bases__ attribute and deepcopy (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, class, deep-copy

Consider the following code snippet (with hopefully clear enough comments):

```
from copy import deepcopy

# Needed to be able to set Container __class__.__bases__ to some custom value
class T:
    pass

class Container(T):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class Consolidate:
    "Class preventing setting of items and attributes"
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        raise TypeError("Cannot modify %s of object" % key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        raise TypeError("Cannot modify %s of object" % key)

def consolidate(obj):
    """
    Don't allow further unintentional modification to the object
    """
    obj.__class__.__bases__ = obj.__class__.__bases__ + (Consolidate,)

state = Container(1)
# deepcopy last item of the state list
theState = deepcopy(state)
# Prevent modifications of the original state
consolidate(state)
# Print some value for the following question
print("bases of theState? %s" % str(theState.__class__.__bases__))
print("ids of the objects: %d %d" % (id(theState), id(state)))
```

I get as output:

```
bases of theState? (<class '__main__.T'>, <class '__main__.Consolidate'>)
ids of the objects: 140148079864408 140148079838488
```

I would like to know why the class Consolidate also is a base of theState, since I thought that by deepcopying I would only add it to the last object in state list.

How can I reach such a goal? (Preventing modification of properties on one object after deepcopying it and without affecting the copied one?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You altered the *class*, which is **shared among all instances**. Copying copies the state of instances, not a class hierarchy, because classes are not seen as state, they are assumed to remain stable.

Rather than mutate the class, create a *second class* and swap out the class of the instances you want to consolidate. Just assign the new class to the `__class__` attribute after copying.

You can create a new class from the old by using the 3-argument version of the [`type()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). This removes the need for your `T` base class too:

```
class Container:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

class Consolidate:
    "Class preventing setting of items and attributes"
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        raise TypeError("Cannot modify %s of object" % key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        raise TypeError("Cannot modify %s of object" % key)

def consolidate(obj):
    # generate a new class object that adds `Consolidated` to the hierarchy.
    cls = type(obj)
    consolidated_class = type(cls.__name__ + 'Consolidated', (Consolidate, cls), {})
    obj.__class__ = consolidated_class
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. How should I change this to work also with classes having in their bases `Generic[R]` where generic is imported from `typing` and `R = TypeVar('R)`?

Trying it plain gives an error

Comment: The error is: "TypeError: Cannot inherit from plain Generic"

Comment: Just to clarify: suppose the class Container is replaced by the following definition:
```
    from typing import TypeVar, Generic

    R = TypeVar('R')
    class Container(Generic[R]):
        def __init__(self, x : R) -> None:
            self.x = x
```

Comment: @DarioBalboni: If you are using type hinting, then just don't create classes dynamically; crete a consolidated container that mixes in `Consolidate`. You can do it dynamically by filtering out the generics but you are really defeating the point of type hinting here.

Comment: @DarioBalboni: put differently: do not generate classes when using type hinting, as type hinting relies on static analysis of types (classes) to work.

Comment: I know that, I'm using such a code only for "debugging" purpose: I have an object that is modified by some part of the code and I don't know which it is. By giving it the class `Consolidate` *after the last modification that should occur* I can run my program and have a type error on the first modification that I do not want, in order to have a clear understanding on which line it is and all the calls that lead to it.

Comment: And I'm doing it dynamically because the real function to consolidate an object does change the __class__.__bases__ attributes of all the subobject also. (Container is a simplified version of it, but my main instance has a dozen of properties storing objects of different classes, each of which has other subobjects).

Creating a mixin of every class I have is an overwhelming task.

Comment: @DarioBalboni: if it is just for debugging, then we need to find you a class generator that'll work with typing (we can just filter those out). We also need to sneak the new class past the `type.__class__` validator, which can sometimes be too picky about what is allowed or not.

Comment: @DarioBalboni: not that I can get this to work right now. Perhaps another time.

Comment: I tried to change your code to filter out the Generic class if found in bases tuple, but that gives the error: `TypeError: __class__ assignment: 'ContainerConsolidated' object layout differs from 'Container'` which is not that informative to me.
Let it be for another time.

Comment: The `typing.Generic` base class uses `__slots__ = ()` which mucks things up when you later subclass again. It's a bit archaic how that all fits together and I haven't found a combination of `__slots__` that'll make it all fit again.